# How to change tr color according to the value from array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Can someone please help me with some code, I have an array of objects with different data in it and then I display it in a table using *ngfor, so now I want to write a code that will check if delivery_to is less than current time it must turn that row red. so for every row that the delivery_to is less than current time it should turn red. here is my array of objects

Here is what I tried but for some reason its turning all the tr red

```js
var array1 = [{
  "order_id": "241918",
  "customer_name": "Marietjie",
  "customer_surname": "Short",
  "total_items": "44",
  "completed_items": "17",
  "percent_complete": "38.64",
  "datetime_received": "2018-07-25 15:18:25",
  "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
  "delivery_from": "12:00",
  "delivery_to": "13:00",
  "completed": "0",
  "shopper": "joel"
 },
 {
  "order_id": "281774",
  "customer_name": "Ashleigh",
  "customer_surname": "Hodge",
  "total_items": "16",
  "completed_items": "0",
  "percent_complete": "0.00",
  "datetime_received": "2018-10-04 15:59:19",
  "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
  "delivery_from": "12:00",
  "delivery_to": "13:00",
  "completed": "0",
  "shopper": null
 },
 {
  "order_id": "232777",
  "customer_name": "Charisse",
  "customer_surname": "Bowles",
  "total_items": "30",
  "completed_items": "0",
  "percent_complete": "0.00",
  "datetime_received": "2018-07-24 17:28:22",
  "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
  "delivery_from": "16:00",
  "delivery_to": "17:00",
  "completed": "0",
  "shopper": null
 }
]

array1.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.delivery_to === "17:00") {
        colortest = 'red';
    }
});
```

Comment: you should come up with a try atleast and then post your issues if you face any

Comment: You mention *ngfor, but there is no html or angular specific code available. please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here

option 1 is to create a directive to compare 2 different times

option 2 is to use for loop in controller like

> you will need moment.js here

```
for(var i = 0; i< array1.length; i++) { 
    if(array1[i].delivery_to <= moment(new Date()).format(hh:mm)) { 
        array1[i].isRedClass = true;
    }
}
```

and in tr tag

```
<tr ng-repeat="array in array1" ng-class="{'redColor':array.isRedClass == true}">
```

and in css

```
.redColor{ 
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to used like that by using `*ngFor`

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of array1" [ngStyle]="{'color': getColor(item)}">{{ item.customer_name }}</li>
</ul>
```

in component add `getColor()` function

```
getColor(item) {
      if(item.customer_name == "Ashleigh"){
        return 'red';
      }

      return 'blue'
  }
```